# Bone doesn't rotate correctly

Tags: rigging, axis

I created a basic armature to test the hands and see if they need something else, and while testing everything was working fine except for two fingers, the three central fingers rotates correctly at the end of them, but the other two at the sides rotates in an odd way. I locked the rotation in Z and Y axis in all of them.
I'll add a video from youtube showing what happens (I don't know how to upload videos in this platform)
[A video showing what happens with the fingers](https://youtu.be/blFqi5S6qW0)

At first I thought I was the weight paint since I parented the mesh with automatic weights for being just a test, but even after paiting them by myself, the problem is still there.
[image: Topology]

[image: Weight Paint lower bone]

[image: Weight Paint Upper bone]

Comment: what does it give if, in Edit mode, you align the orientation of your bones to the orientation of the finger (Ctrl R)